# LDAP bind operation with Perl

Tags: perl, ldap, bind

I am trying to connect a LDAP server. Customer sent following 3 info to me:

1. IP address of LDAP server
2. username
3. password

I am using following code:

```
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new ($ip_address) or die "$@"; 

my $mesg = $ldap->bind ( $username,
                         password => $password,
                                  ) or die $@;

my $result = $ldap->search(
        base   => $base,
        filter => $filter
        attrs  => \@attributes,
        );

die $result->error if $result->code;
```

$result->error value is :

*'000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090728, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection.,*

According to message, bind is not successful. But it should die if it was unsuccessful. I changed password, wrote wrong value, it again did not die.

I dumped $mesg which is return value of bind and saw following message:

*'80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error*

But it is same with the correct username and password too. Username is 'itservice'. I am using as follow:

```
my $mesg = $ldap->bind ( 'itservice',
                         password => $password,
                         ) or die $@;
```

I tried as follow but result is same

```
my $mesg = $ldap->bind ( 'cn=itservice',
                          password => $password,
                             ) or die $@;
```

Is there any other format of using username or password?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~marschap/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod#start_tls

Comment: You may need to specify the correct port.

Comment: Are you able to run a `ldapsearch` query from the command line?

Comment: I am trying following:

ldapsearch -x -LLL -h host -D username -w password

Result is : ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
 additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

Is my format correct?

Comment: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors  search for `52e`. Maybe your credentials are wrong...ask your client to validate the credentials and give you an example ldapsearch that should work.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP Bind request requires a valid DN for the user and not just a user name.
Usually, applications first do a search on userName to retrieve the user DN and then bind as the user.

Comment: I am trying to connect from terminal as follow:

ldapsearch -h host -p 389 -x -D "cn=username" -w password -s base -b "DC=facto,DC=intra,DC=tr" 

But I see following:

ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
 additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C5, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580


Customer says that host,username and password is correct. 
Is my search command wrong?

Comment: "cn=username" is not a full DN. A more appropriate value should be "cn=username,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com". This said, you are interacting with MS AD which is not entirely LDAP compliant, and the additional info string has more details that are entirely specific to AD.